# Create a custom date picker or calender based on 365 number of characters

Tags: javascript, php, loops, datepicker, momentjs

I am getting a string value with 365 chars from an API that tells me the reserved, booked, and available dates where:

0 = Available;
1 = Reserved;
2 = Booked;

Now my question is, how can I pass these values to the moment.js date picker and disable the booked or reserved days with a loop or something?

I am using date range picker with momentjs.
https://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage I don't know how to use a loop and convert each of these character into a data then disable or enable them on the daterangepicker.

My string value from API looks like this:
"11422222224000000000000000000011111114000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Comment: Well you'd have to work out which day of the year each one represents, and convert that into the format your datepicker expects. So yes, a loop would make sense. Where exactly are you stuck with this? P.S. momentJS doesn't include a datepicker by default, so I presume you're using some extra plugin - you'd better tell us which one it is and point to its documentation, if you need help with providing correctly-formatted info to it)

Comment: Hi @ADyson, I am sorry for not being very clear. I have just updated my question and included information about daterangepicker.

Comment: Looks like you need to use the `isInvalidDate: function(date) { .... }` option. Translating a date to a day of the year shouldn't be a big challenge, then you select that character and either return true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem with this code:

```
<?php 
$currentYearList = "https://www.booking-manager.com/api/v2/shortAvailability/". date("Y") ."?companyId=5715&yachtId=" . get_field('yacht_api_id', get_the_ID()) . "&format=3"; ?>
<script>
unavailable_dates = [];
var from = new Date(2022, 0, 1); // Start Date
from =  moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'); //Formatted with momentjs
var custom_dates = <?php echo $currentYearList; ?>  //Data fetched from api;
var date_array = custom_dates.split('');
// Loop through 365 Days.
for (let i = 0; i <= 365; i++) {
            let date = moment(from);
            date.add(i, 'day');
            if(date_array[i] != 0){
            unavailable_dates.push(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
            }
    } </script>
```

Then I passed the unavailable_dates array to daterangepicker like this:

```
rangepickerinput.daterangepicker({ 
isInvalidDate: function(date)
{       
  return !!(unavailable_dates.indexOf(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) > -1);
}
})
```

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question about it - no-one will see your request here, or respond to it. Keep this post just for the solution to your current problem, and make a new question about your next one. But to be honest, if you're just asking a question about what the API is capable of, that's probably a question which can be best answered by reading the API's documentation, or if that doesn't tell you, asking for support from the maintainer of the API. Here at stackoverflow we may not necessarily have specialist knowledge of the exact functionality offered by obscure APIs!

Comment: @ADyson, thank you! I am not very experienced in how things in stack overflow are processed. I will surely make a new question and mark this one as answered.

Comment: No problem. You can take the [tour] if you need an overview of the system. There's also plenty of info in the help centre.

Comment: Also, who will be marking my answer as accepted if I can't?

Comment: You can mark it yourself, but you may have to wait for a little bit. Again, consult the help centre: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer